# How to manage session in flex BlazeDS?

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage session in flex BlazeDS???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591757/how-to-manage-session-in-flex-blazeds)

When I am using sessin using flexContext in blazeDs it is working for one user alone. It is not handled for multiple users. How can I set to store multiple user authentication?